# Do these ternary operator output the same result?

Tags: php, operator-keyword, ternary

Is `$time ?: 3600` equivalent to `isset($time) ? $time : 3600` ?

Thank you all.

Comment: Try it with `$time = 0;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are cases for which they evaluate to the same value, but they are not equivalent.

```
<?php
print $time ?: 3600;
print "\n";
print isset($time) ? $time : 3600;
print "\n\n";

$time = 0;
print $time ?: 3600;
print "\n";
print isset($time) ? $time : 3600;
print "\n\n";

$time = 30;
print $time ?: 3600;
print "\n";
print isset($time) ? $time : 3600;
print "\n\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: time in /home/hq6/PHP/Test2.php on line 2
3600
3600

3600
0

30
30
```

Comment: I've tried with `print $time ?: 3600;`. And it output `3600`. ~~

Comment: @Orion, You have to test the cases both the cases where `$time` is defined, and the cases where `$time` is not defined. You also have to test the case where `$time = 0`.

Comment: I tried with the `not defined` case. It's a little weird.

Comment: @Orion, In order for two expressions to be *equivalent*, it must be the case that they output the same value for **all possible inputs**.

Comment: I see that. I just want to get your first case.

Comment: @Orion, The first case gives correct output but generates a warning.

Answer (score 1):

No, not quite.  `$time ?: 3600` is similar to doing `$time ? $time : 3600`.

The difference would be if `$time` was `0`.  `isset($time)` would return `TRUE` so, you'd get `$time` (`0`), whereas if `$time` was `0` in the first one you'd get `3600`.